# Using cur_column() and sym() in dbplyr

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr, rlang, dbplyr

I have a situation where I need to divide columns in a database, `across()` multiple columns. When the divisor column is fixed, I can use `!!rlang::sym()` to specify the correct column, but I have one instance where the divisor column changes as a function of the current columns name (i.e., `gsub("_lump_sum","_lump_noNAcount",dplyr::cur_column()`).

See example below:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, name ="mtcars", df=mtcars %>% mutate(across(c(gear,carb),~.*2,.names = "{col}_2")))

# This works as intended
tbl(con,"mtcars") %>% 
  summarise(across(any_of(c("vs","am")),~sum(.)/sum(!!sym("wt"))))

# This doesn't work
tbl(con,"mtcars") %>% 
  summarise(across(any_of(c("gear","carb")),~sum(.)/sum(!!sym(paste0(cur_column(),"_2")))))

# Error in `cur_column()`:
# ! Must be used inside `across()`.
```

I realize that `cur_column()` can't work with `!!`, but I also need it evaluated before it goes to the database because `cur_column()` can't be evaluated on the database side either.

Is there a different way of doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The latest development version of `dbplyr` allows for this type of evaluation using `dbplyr::sql`, i,e,:

```
tbl(con,"mtcars") %>% 
  summarise(across(any_of(c("gear","carb")), ~sum(.) / sum(sql(paste0(cur_column(),"_2")))))
```